# SQL server communication issue - Underlying provider failed

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I have a SQL server communication issue intermittently with the following error in the log.
The client communicate the Windows service which is listening on some port and the windows service then  try to connect to SQL server for data. This workflow is fine most of the time but it fails some point of time. I couldn't figure out what's exactly happening.

Please help suggest what could be wrong here.

Sorry if my formatting is wrong.

**Error**

```
System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open.
 ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Connection Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed while attempting to consume the pre-login handshake acknowledgement. This could be because the pre-login handshake failed or the server was unable to respond back in time. The duration spent while attempting to connect to this server was - [Pre-Login] initialization=18153; handshake=9187;
 ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The wait operation timed out   
   --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, SqlAuthenticationProviderManager sqlAuthProviderManager\nat System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions\nat System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions\nat System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open(
at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.<Open>b__36(DbConnection t, DbConnectionInterceptionContext c
at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext](TTarget target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed
at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.Open(DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext
at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.<Open>b__2(
at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Execute>b__0(
at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation
at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action operation
at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()   
   --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open(
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection(Boolean shouldMonitorTransactions
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__5(
at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__0(
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext(
at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.<GetElementFunction>b__1[TResult](IEnumerable`1 sequence
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle[TResult](IEnumerable`1 query, Expression queryRoot
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.DbQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression
at System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source
at SIPServer.SIP.SIPProtocolLogic.CreateResponse17(String Message)
```

Comment: `Please help suggest what could be wrong here.` Exactly what the error says - it had an issue connecting. Perhaps there was a short term networking issue. Perhaps SQL Server ran out of connections. Perhaps etc etc.

Comment: The connection to the database is failing.  Are you using a single server or a pool?  Check the SQL Server logs to see if there is any error messages.  Also the Event Viewer on client and serer.

Comment: @@jdweng: We are using a single server. I checked both the client and server event viewers and SQL server logs but found nothing on that specific transaction timing.